# How to use youtube api to call two or more YouTube account at a time using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Weeks now I have being struggling  with this logic. it's an app that uses YouTube  api.I am able  call the api to display  the information  of a channel  account by using the channel Id I populated in the database. Hence,only one is displaying  but I want it to request  for a quite a number of them not specific number  but I should be able to add up more than one,
so different  channel account, please  ask how can I go about  this in flutter?.

This the Home Screen which supposed to display the channels requested.

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ChannelInfo _channelInfo = ChannelInfo();
  VideosList _videosList = VideosList();
  ScrollController? _scrollController;
  Item _item = Item();
  bool _isloading = true;
  final String _playtlistidd = "";
  String _nextTokenPage = "";
  List<String> _channelIdlistcollector = [];
  //UserInformation _information = UserInformation();
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
  List<String> dataList2 = ["UCsNrLT-M03lvshUuilSJ8XA","UComQiXI7rnjwVU8b6x5epGw","UCC74vXYtWuqDlkoLy6XfcHQ"];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isloading = true;
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _videosList.videos = [];

    _getchannel();
  }

  _getchannel() async {
    //_channelIdlistcollector = (await _information.getDataFromFirebase()) as List<String>;
    // problem identified here

    _channelInfo = (await API_Service.instance.fetchChannelDetails(dataList2,));

    _item = _channelInfo.items![0];
    //print(_item.snippet);

    setState(() {
      _isloading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: _isloading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        //Insert Username here
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            "Hi User",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Categories",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            CategoryButton("Basic 1"),
                            CategoryButton("Basic 2"),
                            CategoryButton("Basic 3")
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6.5,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: dataList2.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return CategoryCardItem(
                                      "Mathematics",
                                        _item.snippet!.title ?? "",
                                      40.00,
                                      "Basic 3",
                                      _item.snippet!.thumbnails!.high!.url ??
                                          "");
                                })),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Popular Subjects",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        GridView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                          children: [
                            PopularCourseCard(
                                courseTitle: "English Language",
                                coursePrice: 35,
                                courseClass: "Basic 3",
                                imgLocation:
                                    "lib/assets/images/english_img.jpg"),
                            PopularCourseCard(
                                courseTitle: "English Language",
                                coursePrice: 35,
                                courseClass: "Basic 3",
                                imgLocation:
                                    "lib/assets/images/english_img.jpg"),
                            PopularCourseCard(
                                courseTitle: "English Language",
                                coursePrice: 35,
                                courseClass: "Basic 3",
                                imgLocation:
                                    "lib/assets/images/english_img.jpg"),
                            PopularCourseCard(
                                courseTitle: "English Language",
                                coursePrice: 35,
                                courseClass: "Basic 3",
                                imgLocation:
                                    "lib/assets/images/english_img.jpg"),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String btnText;

  CategoryButton(@required this.btnText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
      ))),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(btnText),
    );
  }
}
```

This is calling the Youtube Api.

```
class API_Service {
  static const _baseUrl = "www.googleapis.com";
  
  API_Service._instantiate();

  static final API_Service instance = API_Service._instantiate();
  Stream _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots();
  // get the channelId from the database
//Future <dynamic> getDataFromFirebase(){
  //UComQiXI7rnjwVU8b6x5epGw
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var channelInfo;
//}
  //take a list of the item
  // loop through the item to get
// Uri  ?uri;
  //Map<String,String>? headers;
  //supposed to return a list at this place

  Future  <ChannelInfo> fetchChannelDetails(List<String> list) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {
        'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        'id': list[i],
        'key': API_KEY,
      };
      Uri uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, '/youtube/v3/channels', parameters);
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      };
      // get the Channnel.
      Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
      print(response.body);
      channelInfo = channelInfoFromJson(response.body);
      //return channelInfo;
    
    }
  return channelInfo;
  }

  Future<VideosList> fetchVideosFromPlaylist(
      {String? playlistId, String? nextpageTT}) async {
    Map<String, String> parameters = {
      'part': 'snippet',
      'playlistId': playlistId!,
      'maxResults': '8',
      'pageToken': nextpageTT!,
      'key': API_KEY
    };
    Uri uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, '/youtube/v3/playlistItems', parameters);
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    };

    Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
    print(response.body);
//print(data)
    VideosList videosList = videosListFromJson(response.body);
    return videosList;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your problem is when retrieving data from your database. If not, correct me. May you share us some code of how you are currently proceeding with your single YouTube account at a time ?

Comment: As your question seems related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72873777/how-can-i-call-youtube-api-to-display-different-youtube-account-using-different), mentioning it in your question or merging both questions by editing one and deleting the other, if the purpose of the question is the same, may be appropriate.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I have merged the code  with the description  now kindly  please  check it out for me.